# Installing kubernetes on centos 7

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new in kubernetes and I have some doubts about the installation of kubernetes on centos 7, I have read some documentation on some links:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/centos/centos_manual_config/

But I not undestanding which procedure to follow, on first link it show how to install it using kubeadm but at the end of the article on "Limitations" appear that this tool "is a work in progress and these limitations will be addressed in due course", on second link I need to have at least 2 machines, so my question is which is better to use if I will to install it like production.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kubeadm`.

`kubeadm` now can support for multi masters, which is considerable for production.

The `kubeadm` also supplies a secure deployment. It automatically configs [TLS settings](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/kubelet-tls-bootstrapping/) or RBAC for the cluster, which is not included in the "manual installation page".

My advice: play `kubeadm` in your development environment first, so that you see how `kubeadm` deploys a Kubernetes cluster, many components can be deployed by Kubernetes itself. Then, you decide whether use it in your production.

Comment: "kubeadm" is production ready now? not finding any good document for same to create k8s (HA-master) cluster in own VM. can you pls share some docs or link here.

Comment: @TusharDe Please read the official docs... https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/high-availability/

Answer (score 0):

You can follow up the repository made by one of our developer with an additional thing of Horizontal Pod autoscaling of stateless application.

https://github.com/vevsatechnologies/Install-Kubernetes-on-CentOs